bsdiff/bspatch failed to decompress data, bz2/bzlib
I used bsdiff to create patch file, but when I patch this file with bspatch, this error happened.
ERROR 06-01 16:08:04 external/bsdiff/bz2_decompressor.cc:57: Failed to decompress 1040437 bytes of data, error: -1
ERROR 06-01 16:08:04 external/bsdiff/bspatch.cc:318: Failed to read diff stream.
the bsdiff code from aosp: /android11/external/bsdiff/
the code of error point:
size_t prev_avail_in = stream_.avail_in;
int bz2err = BZ2_bzDecompress(&stream_);
if (bz2err != BZ_OK && bz2err != BZ_STREAM_END) {
  LOG(ERROR) << "Failed to decompress" << output_size
             << " bytes of data, error: " << bz2err;
return false;
}

I checked bzlib in bz2，it seem like BZ_SEQUENCE_ERROR, but I don't know how this error happened.
The code in bzlib:
text
int BZ_API(BZ2_bzDecompress) ( bz_stream *strm )
The failed file size is 2.6g, and I tried 6.2g file, it can passed.

Please don't include images when it is trivial to copy and paste the content into a question where it is more usable and less likely to be outlived by the question.
